# Preventing an autocmd from overriding last cmd - :<bang><bang> (:!!)

Tags: autocmd, repeated-commands

I have an autocmd set up like this:

```
au BufWritePost *.sh,*.zsh,.zshrc silent exec "!ctags --language-force=sh %"
```

When I run `:!!<cr>` after saving a file, the command `!ctags --language-force=sh %` is being run.

This does not happen on vim 8.1.

How do I prevent neovim from doing that ?

**EDIT**

First - My mistake, this happens also in vim 8.1 so it's not neovim specific.

Second - I wish to clarify my workflow:

1. Edit a script
2. Save it
3. Run it with `:!./%<cr>`
4. Edit again.
5. Run it again with `:!!<cr>`

When I have the above autocmd in place, `#5` breaks and the autocmd command replaces the last `:!./%<cr>`.

This is what I wish to fix.

Comment: Avi, I've edited your question to be hopefully a bit clearer. If it does not match up with what you intended, please [edit] to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `system()` instead of `:!`. As the question is specific to Neovim, it makes sense to pass command as a List (not supported in Vim!) to execute the application directly (w/o shell):

```
au BufWritePost *.sh,*.zsh,.zshrc
    \ silent call system(['ctags', '--language-force=sh', fnameescape(expand('%'))])
```

Also note that shell quoting rules won't apply then, but you still must escape (at least) spaces in file name.

Comment: I actually thought about this option, but it seemed to me that my workflow is pretty common, so there must be a way to prevent this behavior in vim. I'm sure it's not

Comment: +1
I actually thought about this option before I posted, but it seems to me that my workflow is pretty common, so there must be a way to prevent this behavior in vim. 
Surely a user would want to run his previous command with ```:!!<cr>``` rather than the content of an autocmd (there could be a few of them anyway)...
Just my opinion, I might be wrong here....
(Previous comment should be deleted, accidental)

Answer (score 1):

Do note that vim's documentation says

```
:{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]               *:range!*
            Filter {range} lines through the external program
            {filter}.  Vim replaces the optional bangs with the
            latest given command and appends the optional [arg].
```

So `:!!` should reuse the latest-given command. It's unclear which of the two behaviours (treating autcommands + silent + exec differently or not) is more "correct," but at any rate you could file an issue with NeoVim to change the behaviour.

Comment: I've edited my question - this is not neovim specific. But in any case I'm not sure how the ```:{range}![!]filter [!][arg]``` applies to my situation as I'm not using it in my workflow or my autocmd. (I'm using ```:!{cmd}``` ).In any case my cpoptions does not include ```!``` which would trigger this behaviour. ```:help cpo-!```

Comment: The command `:!!` is covered by this case. Notice the optional second `!`